# How I can mention file as response in RAML 1.0

Tags: raml, mule4

How I can mention file as response in RAML in RAML 1.0
Example: My Mule API is creating file from sql data so How I can mentioned file as response.
I am writing RAML for creating file from sql data?

Is it correct to mention application/csv as response data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file doesn't really have a meaning in a REST API context that RAML models. There is a request body, and a response body. The content type of both can be any MIME type, like application/csv, or application/json, text/xml, etc.

In conclusion application/csv is a valid content type.

Example:

```
resource:
      get:
        body:
          application/json:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/csv:
```